# How to detect when a trigger is fired?

Tags: c#, sql-server, winforms, windows-services, service-broker

I have a project in which I have to send an email to my client when a product is bought. I've been talking to the other developers and we came to the conclusion that there are 3 main steps to accomplish this project:

1. Create a trigger that will be fired when data is inserted into the sales table;
2. Create a Windows Service to "monitor" when this trigger is fired;
3. A WinForms app to send the email.

I know how to send the email via WinForms app, so step 3 is ok.
I read about Service Broker and enabled it on my database. Also, I created the trigger to send a message via Service Broker when data is inserted or updated. I followed [this tutorial](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/service-broker-part-1-service-broker-basics) and came up with this trigger:

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE TRIGGER SendServiceBroker
   ON  dbo.Sales
   AFTER INSERT,UPDATE
AS 
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    DECLARE @ch UNIQUEIDENTIFIER
    DECLARE @msg NVARCHAR(MAX) ;
    BEGIN DIALOG CONVERSATION @ch
        FROM SERVICE [InitiatorService]
        TO SERVICE 'TargetService'
        ON CONTRACT [http://ssb.csharp.at/HelloWorldContract]
        WITH ENCRYPTION = OFF ;
        SET @msg = '<HelloWorldRequest>
                        Gabriela
                    </HelloWorldRequest>' ;
        SEND ON CONVERSATION @ch 
        MESSAGE TYPE [http://ssb.csharp.at/RequestMessage] 
        (@msg) ;
END
GO
```

Also, I found the code for a [Windows Service project](https://github.com/microsoftarchive/msdn-code-gallery-community-s-z/tree/master/Service%20Broker%20Message%20Processor%20Service%20Sample) in Microsoft's GitHub page. I installed the service in my computer and then inserted some data in the Sales table, but nothing happened.
I thought about sending the email directly on the trigger (using `sp_send_dbmail`), but I don't have the necessary permission to do so.
I think that there is something I'm missing in the whole proccess to make it work, but I have no idea of what I have to do to make it work properly.

Comment: A Trigger is fired every time a DML statement it is "tied" to is used on the object it is created on. In this case, the trigger will occur after **every** `UPDATE` and `INSERT` statement on the table `dbo.Sales` is completed.

Comment: Also, don't declare transactions inside a `TRIGGER`. The `TRIGGER` is already encapsulated inside the transaction of the DML statement. Performing things like a `BEGIN TRANSACTION`, `COMMIT` and `ROLLBACK` will likely cause unexpected behaviour. Handle the transactions outside the trigger, not inside it.

Comment: Ok, I removed  the `BEGIN TRANSACTION` and the `COMMIT TRANSACTION` from the trigger and inserted new data, but I still don't know what to do next.

Comment: I think next step would be to look into the RECEIVE tsql command

Comment: According to what I've read, I need to use the Service Broker Message Processor in my C# Windows Service to  get the received message... right?

Comment: check whether messages have been sent and they appear in the receiver/target queue: `select * from sys.transmission_queue;
select cast(message_body as nvarchar(max)), * from InitiatorQueue;  select cast(message_body as nvarchar(max)), * from TargetQueue;`

Comment: Yes, they're all there when I run the `select cast(message_body as nvarchar(max)), * from TargetQueue` command